# unable to run simple groovy program

Tags: spring, groovy

This is my groovy program when I am trying to run this using spring-CLI I am getting error. My groovy is installed correctly.

```
    @RestController
    class Hello{
        @RequestMapping("/")
        String home(){
             return "Hello World"
         }
     }
```

> Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:249)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.findClass(ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.java:84)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
        ... 12 more
```

[Error shown after running spring-cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcFYN.png)

Comment: Please see the link error is posted there

Comment: please post the error here instead.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcFYN.png

Comment: No please put it in the question.

Comment: I am able to run that code with java 1.8 but cannot run it with java 9...
If at all you find the solution with java 9 please let me know.

Comment: @Aviral have you solved? I've the same problem with java 9.

Comment: @Francesco: I was able to run the code using java 1.8 instead of Java 1.9

Comment: I've solved uninstalling all tools related to Java 1.9 and installing Java 1.8.